# how to access incrementing json value dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, count, javascript-objects

This is my object

```
Object {q1: "1", q2: "1"}
```

So far I tried:

```
              var formData = myApp.formToJSON('#personality-test-form');
              formData.q+i;
```

Im getting NaN value when submitted how to access q1 and q2 and so on value dynamically?

Comment: `formData["q"+i]`

Answer (score 4):

To access the property q1 dynamically you need to provide it as a string in bracket notation.

```
formData['q1']
```

which is the same as

```
formData.q1
```

or, if i = 1 then you can dynamically access the property q1 like so:

```
formData['q' + i]
```